# How to write script looping over similar characters to execute a function?

Tags: linux, bash, loops

I am using a toolbox with specific functions already available. For better perspective, I am trying to create a loop for the following command to be executed:

```
FUNCTION_A --replace 1001 3001 --replace 1002 3002 \
           --replace 1003 3003 --replace 1004 3004 --replace 1005 3005
```

... the numbers would go on until `1100` is replaced by `3100`.

What is the best way to write a script to do this, instead of manually typing each pairs of numbers out?

Comment: If the `printf` built into bash supported reuse of arguments, there'd be  fairly clean solution using it, but lacking that, I think @jeremysrofile has the right idea.

Comment: I'm not sure what `FUNCTION_A` is supposed to be, but maybe a for-loop piped into `xargs` would work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If calling `FUNCTION_A` multiple times is acceptable, the easiest method would be a `for` loop:

```
for i in {001..100}; do
    FUNCTION_A --replace 1$i 3$i
done
```

If not, you'll have to be a little trickier:

```
cmd='FUNCTION_A'
for i in {001..100}; do
     cmd+=" --replace 1$i 3$i"
done
$cmd
```

Comment: You'd be better off using an array for the single-command version. `cmd=(FUNCTION_A); for i in {001..100}; do cmd+=(--replace 1$i 3$i); done; "${cmd[@]}"

Comment: haha just did that change myself. Is mine valid as well? I don't understand the `[@]` syntax

Comment: No, you are still building a string. The idea is to build an array instead. That way you don't have to worry about parsing issues; `cmd+=(--replace "1$i" "3$i")` adds exactly three arguments to the command, and would do so even if `$i` contained spaces or quotation marks.
`"${cmd[@]}"` expands the array and executes it as a command, without reparsing any whitespace that might be contained inside the elements. In general, if you're going to build a shell command inside a variable, arrays work better than strings and let you avoid `eval`, unless you have something like dynamic I/O redirection.

Comment: @MarkReed, so, my method works in this case, but would fail in the general case if $i could be something other than just numbers/letters; is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

If the input happened to be a numerically sorted text file with one number per line, it would be as simple as:

`sed -i '/1001/,/1100/s/^1/3/' file.txt`